# Javascript in Partial view how to get it to only appear once if the partial view occurs multiple times on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some html like:

```
<input type="button" value="Show message" class="messagebtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
<img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
<div class="peopleresultsdiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.messagebtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    });
</script>
```

Now all this in a PartialView and this partial View is inside a DisplayFor.

I have to show the DisplayFor three times on one page so you effectively get:

```
<input type="button" value="Show message" class="messagebtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
<img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
<div class="peopleresultsdiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show message" class="messagebtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
<img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
<div class="peopleresultsdiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show message" class="messagebtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
<img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
<div class="peopleresultsdiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    });
</script>
```

So for a start, is this bad practise having the javascript repeated three times on the page?

Second thing is when I clicked one of the buttons I get the Hi alert three times. Makes sense I guess because the script is 
repeated on the screen three times.

Does anyone know how to get around this so I will only get the message once for each button click.

Afterall saying Hi three times is a bit over the top.

Answer (score 1):

> So for a start, is this bad practice having the Javascript repeated three times on the page

Yes, it's pretty bad.  Besides needlessly adding to the page weight page in terms of data transfer and load time, it creates headaches with duplicates, as you've noticed.

One way to get around it is to load the script asynchronously.  Check if your script is already loaded (this goes in the Razor partial view):

```
// check in the global scope for "MyFunctions" object, and a "doWireup" method
if (!window.MyFunctions || !window.MyFunctions.doWireup) {

    // if it doesn't exist, load it from "myfunctions.js"
    $.getScript(@Url.Content("Scripts/myfunctions.js"), function() {

        // execute wireups
        window.MyFunctions.doWireup();
    });
} else { 
    window.MyFunctions.doWireup();
}
```

Your script `myfunctions.js` should be contain the `doWireup` function:

```
// get or create "MyFunctions" object in the global scope
var my = window.MyFunctions || (window.MyFunctions = {});

// add "doWireup" method to it
my.doWireup = function() {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
    });
};
```

This kind of script management can be achieved nicely, along with dependency management, using [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/), or similar.  If you're using MVC4, it might also be worthwhile looking into its [script bundling features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

---

**Edit**

I guess the above might be overkill if you've only got a few short lines of script, like in your example.  A better/straightforward way might be to simply check if the partial view's script has run on the current page.  Just modify to to add a globally-scoped boolean:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (typeof window.HasScriptRun == "undefined")
    {
        window.HasRunScript = true;

        $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
            alert("Hi");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the bundling approach. Another good library for script bundling is cassette: http://getcassette.net/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the javascript from your HTML fragment and simply include it in the header or footer for the page.

Comment: Sometimes the javascript belongs to a partial view. When you use that partial on different views, you had to include the javascript in that views too.

Answer (score 0):

You have three instances of an identical script, so three event listeners are added for each button. Keep in mind that the function in `$(document).ready(function(){})` executes once the page is loaded, when all elements are already existing in the DOM.

The selector `$('.findpersonbtn')` might match more than one element (3 in your case), and a click listener is added to each of these matching elements. You don't have to run the code for each instance, jQuery already does that for you.

By the way the selector does not match anything in your example, but I suppose `findpersonbtn` was a class of each button instance in your original code

Inside the function, `this` will refer to the element that is clicked. You could have it as a jQuery by doing `$(this)`. So, for example if each button had a different message to display, you could:

```
<input type="button" value="Show message 1" class="findpersonbtn messagebtn btn" data-message="hi"/>
<input type="button" value="Show message 2" class="findpersonbtn messagebtn btn" data-message="hello"/>
<input type="button" value="Show message 3" class="findpersonbtn messagebtn btn" data-message="salut"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('message'));
  });
});
</script>
```